# Angular filter list with multiple checkboxes

Tags: angular

I want to implement checkbox filter in an Angular project where I need to implement filters.
I want the ability to filter by individual course category and also when I click on both checkboxes
it should display both selected courses. Any help would be appreciated, here is the stack blitz link:

https://angular-checkbox-template-reset-eftthm.stackblitz.io/

I am not able to figure it out, any help would be appreciated. If someone could please modify my stack blitz example I would appreciate it.

my ts file with the object and my filter pipe:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

const COURSES = [
  {
    courseId: 1,
    courseName: "Course A",
    courseCategory: "Mandatory & Compliance",
    courseImg: "https://picsum.photos/id/10/380/200",
    mandatory: true,
    completed: false,
    expiry: null
  },
  {
    courseId: 2,
    courseName: "Course B",
    courseCategory: "Mandatory & Compliance",
    courseImg: "https://picsum.photos/id/11/380/200",
    mandatory: true,
    completed: false,
    expiry: null
  },
  {
    courseId: 3,
    courseName: "Course C",
    courseCategory: "Mandatory & Compliance",
    courseImg: "https://picsum.photos/id/12/380/200",
    mandatory: true,
    completed: false,
    expiry: null
  },
  {
    courseId: 4,
    courseName: "Course D",
    courseCategory: "Business Skills",
    courseImg: "https://picsum.photos/id/13/380/200",
    mandatory: false,
    completed: true,
    expiry: null
  },
  {
    courseId: 5,
    courseName: "Course E",
    courseCategory: "Business Skills",
    courseImg: "https://picsum.photos/id/14/380/200",
    mandatory: false,
    completed: false,
    expiry: null
  },
  {
    courseId: 6,
    courseName: "Course F",
    courseCategory: "Business Skills",
    courseImg: "https://picsum.photos/id/15/380/200",
    mandatory: false,
    completed: true,
    expiry: null
  },
  {
    courseId: 7,
    courseName: "Course G",
    courseCategory: "Leadership & Management",
    courseImg: "https://picsum.photos/id/16/380/200",
    mandatory: false,
    completed: false,
    expiry: null
  },
  {
    courseId: 8,
    courseName: "Course H",
    courseCategory: "Personal Effectiveness",
    courseImg: "https://picsum.photos/id/17/380/200",
    mandatory: false,
    completed: false,
    expiry: null
  },
  {
    courseId: 9,
    courseName: "Course I",
    courseCategory: "Leadership & Management",
    courseImg: "https://picsum.photos/id/18/380/200",
    mandatory: false,
    completed: false,
    expiry: null
  },
  {
    courseId: 10,
    courseName: "Course J",
    courseCategory: "Mandatory & Compliance",
    courseImg: "https://picsum.photos/id/19/380/200",
    mandatory: true,
    completed: false,
    expiry: null
  },
  {
    courseId: 11,
    courseName: "Course K",
    courseCategory: "Personal Effectiveness",
    courseImg: "https://picsum.photos/id/20/380/200",
    mandatory: false,
    completed: false,
    expiry: null
  },
  {
    courseId: 12,
    courseName: "Course L",
    courseCategory: "Mandatory & Compliance",
    courseImg: "https://picsum.photos/id/21/380/200",
    mandatory: true,
    completed: false,
    expiry: null
  },
  {
    courseId: 13,
    courseName: "Course M",
    courseCategory: "Business Skills",
    courseImg: "https://picsum.photos/id/22/380/200",
    mandatory: false,
    completed: false,
    expiry: null
  },
  {
    courseId: 14,
    courseName: "Course N",
    courseCategory: "Business Skills",
    courseImg: "https://picsum.photos/id/23/380/200",
    mandatory: false,
    completed: false,
    expiry: null
  },
  {
    courseId: 15,
    courseName: "Course O",
    courseCategory: "Mandatory & Compliance",
    courseImg: "https://picsum.photos/id/24/380/200",
    mandatory: true,
    completed: false,
    expiry: null
  },
  {
    courseId: 16,
    courseName: "Course P",
    courseCategory: "Leadership & Management",
    courseImg: "https://picsum.photos/id/25/380/200",
    mandatory: false,
    completed: false,
    expiry: null
  },
  {
    courseId: 17,
    courseName: "Course Q",
    courseCategory: "Business Skills",
    courseImg: "https://picsum.photos/id/26/380/200",
    mandatory: false,
    completed: false,
    expiry: null
  },
  {
    courseId: 18,
    courseName: "Course R",
    courseCategory: "Business Skills",
    courseImg: "https://picsum.photos/id/27/380/200",
    mandatory: false,
    completed: false,
    expiry: null
  },
  {
    courseId: 19,
    courseName: "Course S",
    courseCategory: "Leadership & Management",
    courseImg: "https://picsum.photos/id/28/380/200",
    mandatory: false,
    completed: false,
    expiry: null
  },
  {
    courseId: 20,
    courseName: "Course T",
    courseCategory: "Mandatory & Compliance",
    courseImg: "https://picsum.photos/id/29/380/200",
    mandatory: true,
    completed: false,
    expiry: null
  },
];

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild("switchColorSuccess", { static: false }) switchColorSuccess: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("switchColorSuccessTwo", { static: false }) switchColorSuccessTwo: ElementRef;
  name = "Checkbox filter";
  courses;
  filterBy?: string = "all";
  courseCategory;

  constructor() {
    this.courses = COURSES;
    
  }

  toggle() {
    if (this.switchColorSuccess.nativeElement.checked) {
      this.courses.filterBy({courseCategory: "Mandatory & Compliance"});
    } else if (this.switchColorSuccessTwo.nativeElement.checked) {
      this.courses.filterBy({courseCategory: "Business Skills"});
    } 
  }
}
```

My filter pipe file:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "filtercourses"
})
export class FiltercoursesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], courseCategory: string): any {
    console.log(courseCategory);
     if (courseCategory == "Mandatory & Compliance") {
      return items.filter(item => {
        return item.courseCategory === true;
      });
    }
      else if (courseCategory == "Business Skills") {
        return items.filter(item => {
          return item.courseCategory === true;
        });
    // } else
    //   return items.filter(item => {
    //     return item.courseCategory === courseCategory;
    //   });
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

My HTML template file:

```html
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>

        <div class="field">
            <input #switchColorSuccess type="checkbox" name="switchColorSuccess" class="switch is-success"
                        >
            <label for="switchColorSuccess">Mandatory & Compliance</label>
        </div><br/>
        <div class="field">
            <input #switchColorSuccessTwo type="checkbox" name="switchColorSuccessTwo" class="switch is-success"
                        >
            <label for="switchColorSuccessTwo">Business Skills</label>
        </div><br/>
        <button type="button" (click)="toggle()">Apply filter</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 0 auto;">
        <ul fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
            <li *ngFor="let course of courses | filtercourses:filterBy">
                <h3>{{course.courseName}}</h3>
                <h4>{{course.courseCategory}}</h4>
                <img src="{{course.courseImg}}" class="img" width="200"/>
    </li>
```

Comment: You mention no less than 3 times how you'd appreciate any help, but don't provide us with the source code you need help with ... I for one would prefer that your appreciation of our expertise would take the form of respecting our time by making your question easy to answer, by making the relevant information readily available.

Comment: You have attached a stackblitz demo .but no code is shared.
Try to add
1) Your TS file.Which is your initial array from which you want to filter.
2)Initial array.
3)Property with which you want to filter the initalarray and show the final result

Comment: Sorry I just added the code files, I want the ability to filter by individual course category when I click on the checkbox, also when I click on both checkboxes
it should display both selected courses.

Answer (score 0):

Your **Filter Pipe** to changed to.

```
  transform(items: any[], courseCategory: string[]): any { //courseCategory is an array of strings.So that whichever values you want to filter out with you can add ti that here.If you want to filter both 'Business Skills' & 'Leadership & Management' you pass it like ['Business Skills','Leadership & Management']
    if (!items || !courseCategory) { //if either if its null it will return the full results
      return items;
    }
    return items.filter(item => {
      return courseCategory.some(coursename => {
        return item.courseCategory === coursename;
      });
    });
    return null;
  }
```

Yout HTML to be changed to below
**HTML**

```
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let course of courses | filtercourses:filterarray"> //whichever courses you want to filter you can push it in here
      <h3>{{course.courseName}}</h3>
      <h4>{{course.courseCategory}}</h4>
      <img src="{{course.courseImg}}" class="img" width="200"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

iam focusing on the **pipe** only since I think you know how to push all the checked inputs to that array.If you want help with that too pls feel free to comment.

Adding toggle function too.

```
  filterarray: string[] = [];
```

```
  toggle() {
     this.filterarray=[]; //resetting the array each time you click on filter
    if (this.switchColorSuccess.nativeElement.checked) {
      
      this.filterarray.push("Mandatory & Compliance");
    }
    if (this.switchColorSuccessTwo.nativeElement.checked) {
      
      this.filterarray.push("Business Skills");
    }
  }
```

Even though the above toggle will work.Please see checkbox input type documention too if you want to optimize it further.

Comment: Could you also help me with pushing all the checked inputs to that array, I am new to JavaScript and Angular. Do I need to make in changes in toggle()?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Yes you have to add changes in toggle().I will add that too

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works perfectly. One last question, if I uncheck one of the checkboxes how do I only show data for the selected checkbox?

Comment: This code is capable of what you asked.if you uncheck one and click apply only the courses of selected one will be visible.pls check .If you dont want to use Apply filter button.You have to write on change functions.

Comment: If it helped,you can upvote and accept it as your answer

Comment: Actually when I uncheck the checkbox I want it to remove the data. I will work on it, if I am not able to figure out I will post here again. Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: I want to keep the apply filter button, but when I uncheck one of the checkboxes it should remove that data from the list the only display data for the other checked checkbox. Is it possible to do that?